# ReferenceError: module is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, syntax-error, node-modules

So i have been trying to run this web app  and at first it showed

(node:12960) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
C:\Users\J\react-messenger\stream-chat-boilerplate-api\src\index.js:1
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

And then i went to put set the type: module in the package.json but it gave me this error

ReferenceError: module is not defined

```
at file:///C:/Users/J/react-messenger/stream-chat-boilerplate-api/src/index.js:38:1
```

Here is my code:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import compression from 'compression';

const api = express();

api.use(cors());
api.use(compression());
api.use(helmet());
api.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
api.use(bodyParser.json());

api.listen(process.env.PORT, error => {
    if (error) {
        console.warn(error);
        process.exit(1);
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line array-callback-return
    fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, 'routes')).map(file => {
        require('./routes/' + file)(api);
    });

    console.info(
        `Running on port ${process.env.PORT} in ${
            process.env.NODE_ENV
        } mode. `
    );
});

module.exports = api;
```

I dont know what am doing wrong

Comment: As it says: Set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You are mixing ES imports with CommonJS - at bottom of file you have `module.exports = api;` which is CJS terminology. The ES module equivalent is:

```
export default api
```

Comment: Can I use a `require` cjs module in .mjs file using an import statement

Comment: @Gary yes you can.

Comment: This is the straight forward answer I needed!

Comment: Found my solution with this answer ! Thanks.